# How to share site link to facebook in aem?

Tags: java, aem

Is somebody implementing this in cq5? I have to add button which will shere my site link to facebook. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AEM ACS Commons provides the sample and code for the facebook share integration. you can find the details [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-social-integration) and the actual component implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-social-integration/tree/master/content/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/social-integration/facebook/components/widgets/sightly/share)